# Can I apply methods to a model.where condition to get all object created in specific month?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I am trying to apply the `.where` function on a model of mine called `news` to get all news `published(represented by DateTime)` in a certain month.

I've tried to get the following code snippet to work:

```
news.where(:publish_time.strftime('%B %Y') => "month year")
```

But there does not seem to be support for such a call as `:publish_time` is a symbol rather than value.

Is there any other way to do this or should I create a column that contains the month & year of publishing?

I've found other sources that claim you should create a span of `DateTime` and check if the object is within that span. That does, however, feel extremely DRY-prone and not open for additions.

Answer (score 3):

Add this in your News model:

```
scope :published_in_month, ->(datetime) { where(publish_time: datetime.beginning_of_month..datetime.end_of_month) }
```

Then you can do:

```
News.published_in_month(some_datetime)
```

ie:

```
News.published_in_month(Datetime.new(2019, 06, 01))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [by_star gem](https://github.com/radar/by_star) to easily query date / time ranges in Active Record.

```
News.by_month(Date.today)
```